# How set session value in dependency injection

Tags: c#, session, autofac

I use this code and getting HttpExeption, when try get access to session value:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterControllers();
        builder.Register(c => GetTransform()).As<ITransform>();
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private ITransform GetTransform()
    {
        if (Session["Transform"] == null)
            Session["Transform"] = new Transform();

        return (ITransform)Session["Transform"];
    }
```

How to set session value to controller using Autofac resolve/injection

Comment: Can you show the class the depends on `ITransform` (via constructor injection) or that tries to resolve `ITransform` directly?

Comment: Yacoub: 
`public class MainController : Controller
    {
        private ITransform Transform;

        public MainController(ITransform transform)
        {
            Transform= transform;
        }
        ...

    }`

Comment: Could you share the error detail (stack trace, exception message, etc.) ? Do you only inject ITransform while there is an active HttpContext ?

Comment: Would this be a better solution?  http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Autofac.Mvc5/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/AutofacWebTypesModule - inject the `HttpContextBase` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `Session` property that you are accessing in the `GetTransform` method is a property of the `HttpApplication` object that is defined in `Global.asax.cs`.

I am assuming that this is not the session object that you are interested in. What you want (I assume) is the session object that is bound to the current request (which is the same as accessing the `Session` property from inside the controller).

Here is how you can do it:

```
private ITransform GetTransform()
{
    var session = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;

    if (session["Transform"] == null)
        session["Transform"] = new Transform();

    return (ITransform)session["Transform"];
}
```